# Informatica Powerexchange post sql greenplum writer

Tags: informatica, greenplum, informatica-powerexchange

I am facing issue in informatica target greenplum writer post sql..I have query that is running fine on database but when I am placing the query in post sql its not working ,there are lot of case statements present in query. When I tried removing couple of case statements then its working fine using post sql otherwise throwing fatal error.Can someone in the past faced similar scenario and can provide solution how to deal with it.Is there any limitations with informatica greenplum writer?

Answer (score 0):

Some things to consider -

1. Is the user that youre using to run SQL in database is same as informatica user?
2. Is the SQL youre running in DB is same as infa post process ?
3. When you run the SQL in the DB, does the target table has all the indexes etc. ?
4. Does informatica loads large amount of data? Doesn infa drops indexes before loading ?

Now, please note post load SQL is just a simple SQL runs all at once. So, post SQL can be slow

1. if you do not have an index on target,
2. if you have large amount of data,
3. if table size grows a lot because of infa load,
4. if the table has stale statistics,
5. if table involved in SQL case statements is large

So, i recommend, please move the post SQL to informatica mapping because informatica inserts or updates in bunch and not apply the changes all together like a post SQL. Your performance will be much better.

Comment: Hi @Koushik-Thank you for your reply.While running the post sql using (Relational writer) its finishing in 1 min but we need to move away from relational writer to greenplum writer and with greenplum writer same query started throwing issues.We are using 25 case statements in sql query.If we run with 21 case statements its working fine but if we use more than that it started throwing fatal errors in informatica.I ran the sql manually in db and its running fine not sure if greenplum writer has any limitations like it can handle only 21 case statements and also union all is not working fine

Comment: Is it the exact 4 case statements that you need to remove to make it work? Or can you remove any other case statements and it works too? If the former, perhaps there is something odd with one of the 4 statements, like missing schema reference, or using function that is not available to the user, etc.

Comment: Agree with @Maciejg, can you test with just those 4 statements? That way you can eliminate specific issues. Now, if 4 statements doesnt work, you know what is the issue. If they works, then i think youre right, some limitation or perf problem when it has to process lot of logic.

Comment: In such case, when the logic would be too much to handle, perhaps you could split the statement into two?

Comment: @KoushikRoy,@Maceijg - I have tried both cases if we split and run then its working but if we consolidate it and run it all together its not working...not sure what kind of limitation it is. If I remove other 4 statements and keep these 4 statements then also its working fine as well.Surely,it looks like some sort of limitation within greenplum writer.

Comment: @KoushikRoy,@maceijg- Just fyi, same query is working fine when relational writer been used but not working with greenplum writer.So i am sure its limitation issue it seems..howver if you have any thoughts pls let me know